# Translate relational algebra relation to SQL (INTERSECT)?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

Could you help me translating this relational algebra relation to SQL?

```
For a given X(A), Y(A) and T(A):

X UNION (Y INTERSECTS T)
```

Here's my try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (R UNION S) INTERSECT T;
```

Is this correct? And are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: No MySQL does not support INTERSECT ... you can emulate the function INTERSECT https://www.google.nl/search?q=mysql+INTERSECT

Comment: Or really? I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: What does "translate RA to SQL" mean? Write a query that returns the same result? Write an expression with parallel form? How were you *told* to "translate" in your class? What version of RA were you told to use? When you googled for SQL INTERSECT what did you find? Please read [ask]. PS See my answer.

Comment: It's not clear why you started with X, Y, and T and operated on R, S, and T in your translation.  It's as well to be self-consistent, even if it doesn't matter very much which set of names you use.  If your tables are all single columns, then you'd need: `SELECT Z.A FROM (SELECT A FROM X UNION SELECT A FROM Y) AS Z JOIN T ON Z.A = T.A`, I believe, or something pretty close to that.

Comment: [Convert SQL SELECT query to corresponding/equivalent relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44411096/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL has INTERSECT and so do many products. MySQL doesn't.

(There's no single "relational algebra" but typically:) Relational algebra INTERSECT is limited to when its input relations have the same columns, and acts like NATURAL JOIN.

So the obvious SQL analogue is NATURAL JOIN. Or JOIN USING all columns. Or (INNER) JOIN ON equality of every pair of same-named columns followed by SELECT of one of each pair.